# When overloading the equality operator==, should one check for reference equality first?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

When overloading operator==(), I currently do

```
bool operator==(const X& lhs, const X& rhs)
{
    return &lhs == &rhs || /* member comparisons ... */;
}
```

meaning I check first for reference equality of the objects and then for equality for all the members. Is this the "proper" way to do it? Are there any gotchas or things to remember? Is this implementation the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: It's a fairly standard optimization if the compare is non-trivial.

Comment: When does a comparison become non-trivial? If there are just 2-3 primitives to compare, should I check for reference equality?

Comment: Knowing exactly when it is faster to do the check is a micro-optimization. Since it involves a branch, it will depend on what the common case is and what the run-time patterns are. So it's hard to do better than hand-waving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self comparison is usually rare, unless you are an immutable internal pImpl that is usually only compared via `==` in an `unordered_` container after a `std::hash` collision of your regular wrapper, or something similar.

Optimizing for rare cases is often a bad idea.  It adds complexity to the code, and increases testing overhead.

An exception can exist if the comparison is expensive or boundlessly expensive, so that the cost of a failed pointer comparison at the start is trivial.  Another exception is where self comparison is unusually expensive, and almost-self (which would be almost as expensive) is exceedingly rare, while self comparison sometimes happens.

The short answer is, keep your code simple, worry about large-order blowups, don't needlessly pessimize, and optimize after actually noticing a performance problem (even if it is just "wow, that was slow", or Monte Carlo profiling).

Comment: I'm coming from Java, where reference equality is the only thing the == operator does. Also the (eclipse-generated) .equals() method always included a reference equality check in it. So it actually was a bit more than a performance question. I've just seen it so often and didn't question it, but learning C++ properly made me question it.

Comment: @timo Java objects correspond to the `pImpl` internal implementation detail above: which moves you toward the check.  That is because it is easy to end up with one object and many 'names' for it in Java.  In C++ this would only be a significant danger for special object types.  In C++ the more common case is value types, or (smart) pointer held types where pointer validity (and maybe equality) needs be checked before `==` anyhow.  Now I am not saying 'this will break your code', but I am saying 'meh, worth skipping', and simpler code is a virtue worth striving for.