# C++ self comparison check

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

For assignment operator we check: `if(this == &rhs)`, why not to check the same for self comparison in `bool operator==(const MyClass& rhs)`?

For assignment we want to avoid to self assign a bunch of data. The same is for comparison. If it is a good practice to check for assignment, then it should be for comparison too.

Comment: `s/we check/some of us sometimes check/`

Comment: For assignment it may well be critical to check, whereas for comparison it would just be a (possibly premature) performance optimisation.

Comment: You can do that if you want to and it makes sense. You can also not perform that check in the assignment operator when it's not necessary.

Comment: "Self comparison is usually rare (...) Optimizing for rare cases is often a bad idea. It adds complexity to the code, and increases testing overhead." - from the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27281163/96780) to the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27280601/96780).

Comment: Probably related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691007/whats-the-right-way-to-overload-operator-for-a-class-hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Because we usually associate `==` to check whether the data is exactly identical or not. `this == &something` checks whether they are pointers to the same thing or not.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    bool operator==(const A& rhs) const { return this == &rhs ; }

    int a ;
};

int main() {
    A a {2}, b{2};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a == b);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is false even as `a.a == b.a`.

[Here](http://ideone.com/yuwMgh) is the sample.

Comment: You could check if the pointers are the same return true immediately.

Comment: That is what I am checking in this code. `this == &rhs` checks the pointers and yet it returns `false` and not `true` because they point to different objects.